# Creating a draggable list in android?

Tags: android, list, view, drag

I need a list view where the user can drag items to rearrange them.

So far, the solution seems to be this library: https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/blob/master/library/src/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortListView.java

but I cannot get it to work with my custom list-item. the differences don't seem drastic; my item has 3 textviews (title, description, date label) but I can't find any similar problems online.

As DSLV has been abandoned long ago, are is there a better alternative? any tips to making dslv work?

Comment: There are a few suggestions right here on this site. Search for _"draggable list items android"_ or something along those lines.

Comment: "I cannot get it to work" -- this is not an especially useful description of your symptoms. Does the app crash, and if so, where and with what stack trace? Does it rain frogs? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare It crashes on inflating the view. I've looked through the code, and it's not impossible to get things working as they are now. It just seems way too involved and I'd rather find a modern library to implement rather than work around this abandoned project.

Comment: Well, the problem is that asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic nowadays for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh. Understood.